# Memory and Frame Rate Issues in FFmpeg Video Streaming

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm currently working with FFmpeg libraries to generate a video stream for the first time. As a newcomer to this field, I'm still exploring and experimenting with the code. For testing purposes, I've set up Nginx as the server and VLC as the client to view the stream. During these initial tests, I'm loading an image at the start and processing it for each frame, which is then sent for encoding and streaming.

I've encountered a couple of interconnected issues:

1. When I process frames as quickly as possible, I can see the stream playing seemingly in real-time. However, I've noticed that the computer's memory usage skyrockets, rapidly consuming gigabytes of memory within seconds.
2. I suspect that this memory issue is related to the fact that I might be generating frames at a much higher rate than FFmpeg can handle for encoding and streaming. It seems like there may be buffering of data occurring somewhere. To address this, I introduced a 'sleep_for' delay to throttle the frame rate down to approximately 40 frames per second, instead of the 4000 fps I get without throttling. While this does contain memory growth, VLC no longer plays the stream in real-time. Instead, it appears to wait, play for a couple of seconds, go idle, and then resume playing intermittently.

I've tried adjusting the frame rate settings, specifically:

```
(*codec_context)->time_base = (AVRational){1, 30};
```

and

```
frame_yuv->pts = (1.0 / 30) * 90 * frame_count;
```

Based on my research and information from Stack Overflow, these settings seem correct. They indicate that the stream is meant to be played at 30 frames per second and that I've set the timing accordingly (where 90 represents the sample rate used by FFmpeg).

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or insights into resolving these issues.

```
extern "C" {
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
    #include <libavutil/opt.h>
    #include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}

#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>

void InitializeFFMPG(AVCodecContext** codec_context, AVFormatContext** format_context, int width, int height) {
    avformat_network_init();
    //av_register_all(); // no longer needed
    
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(format_context, nullptr, "flv", "rtmp://localhost/live/stream"); // RTMP URL
    
    const AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    if (!codec) {
        std::cerr << "avcodec_find_encoder err." << std::endl;
    }
    
    *codec_context = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!*codec_context) {
        std::cerr << "codec_context err." << std::endl;
    }
    
    (*codec_context)->width = width;
    (*codec_context)->height = height;
    (*codec_context)->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    (*codec_context)->time_base = (AVRational){1, 30};
    if (avcodec_open2(*codec_context, codec, nullptr) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Could not open codec" << std::endl;
    }
    
    AVStream* stream = avformat_new_stream(*format_context, codec);
    if (!stream) {
        std::cerr << "Could not create stream" << std::endl;
    }
    
    avcodec_parameters_from_context(stream->codecpar, *codec_context);
    
    if (avio_open(&(*format_context)->pb, "rtmp://localhost/live/stream", AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Count not open output URL" << std::endl;
    }
    
    if (avformat_write_header(*format_context, nullptr) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Could not write header" << std::endl;
    }
}

int frame_count = 0;

void ConvertRGBToYUV(AVFrame* frame_rgb, AVFrame* frame_yuv, struct SwsContext* sws_ctx) {
    sws_scale(sws_ctx, frame_rgb->data, frame_rgb->linesize, 0, frame_rgb->height, frame_yuv->data, frame_yuv->linesize);
}

void EncodeAndStreamFrame(AVCodecContext* codec_context, AVFormatContext* format_context, 
    unsigned char** framebuffer, int width, int height, struct SwsContext* sws_ctx) {
    AVFrame* frame_rgb = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame_rgb) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to allocate frame_rgb" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    frame_rgb->format = AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24;
    frame_rgb->width  = width;
    frame_rgb->height = height;

    if (av_image_alloc(frame_rgb->data, frame_rgb->linesize, width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, 32) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to allocate RGB image buffer" << std::endl;
        av_frame_free(&frame_rgb);
        return;
    }
    
    memcpy(frame_rgb->data[0], *framebuffer, width * height * 3);
    
    AVFrame* frame_yuv = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame_yuv) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to allocate frame_yuv" << std::endl;
        av_frame_free(&frame_rgb);
        return;
    }

    frame_yuv->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    frame_yuv->width  = width;
    frame_yuv->height = height;

    if (av_frame_get_buffer(frame_yuv, 32) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to allocate YUV frame buffer" << std::endl;
        av_frame_free(&frame_rgb);
        av_frame_free(&frame_yuv);
        return;
    }
    
    frame_yuv->pts =  (1.0 / 30) * 90 * frame_count;
    
    ConvertRGBToYUV(frame_rgb, frame_yuv, sws_ctx);

    if (avcodec_send_frame(codec_context, frame_yuv) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error sending YUV frame for encoding" << std::endl;
        av_frame_free(&frame_rgb);
        av_frame_free(&frame_yuv);
        return;
    }

    while (1) {
        AVPacket pkt = { 0 };
        av_packet_unref(&pkt);
        pkt.data = NULL;
        pkt.size = 0;

        int ret = avcodec_receive_packet(codec_context, &pkt);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
            break;
        } else if (ret < 0) {
            break;
        }

        if (av_interleaved_write_frame(format_context, &pkt) < 0) {
            av_packet_unref(&pkt);
            break;
        }
        av_packet_unref(&pkt);
    }

    av_frame_free(&frame_rgb);
    av_frame_free(&frame_yuv);
}

void ProcessFrame(const unsigned char* in, unsigned char*& framebuffer, int width, int height) {
    float cosine = std::abs(std::cos(frame_count / 300.f));
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < width * height * 3; ++i)
        framebuffer[i] = (unsigned char)((float)in[i] * cosine);
}

int main() {
    AVCodecContext *codec_context = nullptr;
    AVFormatContext *format_context = nullptr;
    int width = 320, height = 160;
    InitializeFFMPG(&codec_context, &format_context, width, height);
    
    struct SwsContext* sws_ctx = sws_getContext(width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
                                                width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                                                0, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!sws_ctx) {
        return 0;
    }

    unsigned char* framebuffer_in = new unsigned char[width*height*3];
    unsigned char* framebuffer = new unsigned char[width*height*3];
    memset(framebuffer, 0x0, width * height * 3);
    std::ifstream ifs("C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/ocean.ppm", std::ios::binary);
    std::string header;
    ifs >> header;
    uint32_t w, h, bpc;
    ifs >> w >> h >> bpc;
    ifs.ignore();
    ifs.read((char*)framebuffer_in, w * h * 3);
    ifs.close();
    
    auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    while (1) {
        ProcessFrame(framebuffer_in, framebuffer, width, height);
        EncodeAndStreamFrame(codec_context, format_context, &framebuffer, width, height, sws_ctx);
        frame_count++;
        std::chrono::milliseconds frameDelay(20); 
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(frameDelay);
        auto end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end_time - start_time);
        double fps = static_cast<double>(frame_count) / duration.count();
        fprintf(stderr, "\r%f fps", fps);
        fflush(stderr);
    }

    // Cleanup
    delete[] framebuffer;
    delete[] framebuffer_in;
    avcodec_close(codec_context);
    avformat_close_input(&format_context);
    avformat_free_context(format_context);
    avcodec_free_context(&codec_context);

    return 0;
}
```